# Viewport width desconsiderando o scrollbar do body

Tags: css, viewport

Tenho um HTML dizendo que o scrollbar terá 8px, assim:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}
```

Nesse HTML tera uma galeria de imagem, onde cada foto ocupará 20% da largura do body, então fiz assim:

```
.foto_galeria{
    width: 20vw;
    float: left;
}
```

E aí que acabo tendo problemas, quando checo o tamanho do meu `body` vejo que ele tem 1912px, e quando vou checar o tamanho da DIV foto_galeria, ela ta com 480px, e 480 X 4 = 1920 e não 1912, então ele está levando em consideração o tamanho do scrollbar, como solucionar isso?

Pois da forma que está, a DIV foto_galeria quebra, não fica uma ao lado da outra. Ela fica apenas em 4 colunas, pois não cabe 5 no body.

Segue o código completo:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 8px;
 background-color: $marrom;
}
.foto_galeria{
  width: calc(20vw - 2px);
  height: calc(20vw - 2px);
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="foto_galeria">1</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">2</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">3</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">4</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">5</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Cara vc tem que colocar o código completo pelo menos de forma que a gente possa simular o seu problema ai... Só com o que vc postou só da pare te ajudar no chute...

Comment: Opa, coloquei o código todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa resetar a margem do `body`, senão ela será incluída no cálculo das divs, fazendo com que elas não caibam na largura do body, porque o `vw` irá pegar a largura total da janela (sem a barra de rolagem).

O body tem margem de 8px, logo o `vw` irá pegar 1912px e tentar distribuir em 1896px (1912px menos 16px das margens laterais do body).

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 8px;
 background-color: $marrom;
}
.foto_galeria{
  width: calc(20vw - 2px);
  height: calc(20vw - 2px);
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="foto_galeria">1</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">2</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">3</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">4</div>
<div class="foto_galeria">5</div>
```